# Compiling Issues with Mex and IT++

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I am having issues compiling the It++ library. I have installed it correctly and have tested it with a simple example without mex.

mex it_mex_fkmigration.cpp -litpp

```
it_mex_fkmigration.cpp:1:25: error: itpp/itcomm.h: No such file or directory
it_mex_fkmigration.cpp:2:26: error: itpp/itmex.h: No such file or directory
it_mex_fkmigration.cpp:4: error: expected namespace-name before ';' token
it_mex_fkmigration.cpp:4: error: '<type error>' is not a namespace
it_mex_fkmigration.cpp:6: error: 'mxArray' has not been declared
it_mex_fkmigration.cpp:6: error: expected ',' or '...' before '*' token
it_mex_fkmigration.cpp:6: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'mxArray' with no type
it_mex_fkmigration.cpp: In function 'void mexFunction(int, int**, int, int)':
it_mex_fkmigration.cpp:9: error: 'mexErrMsgTxt' was not declared in this scope
it_mex_fkmigration.cpp:10: error: 'mexErrMsgTxt' was not declared in this scope
it_mex_fkmigration.cpp:13: error: 'bvec' was not declared in this scope
it_mex_fkmigration.cpp:13: error: expected `;' before 'input_bits'  
it_mex_fkmigration.cpp:16: error: 'cvec' was not declared in this scope
it_mex_fkmigration.cpp:16: error: expected `;' before 'output_symbols'
it_mex_fkmigration.cpp:17: error: 'QPSK' was not declared in this scope
it_mex_fkmigration.cpp:17: error: expected `;' before 'qpsk'
it_mex_fkmigration.cpp:19: error: 'output_symbols' was not declared in this scope
it_mex_fkmigration.cpp:19: error: 'qpsk' was not declared in this scope
it_mex_fkmigration.cpp:19: error: 'input_bits' was not declared in this scope
it_mex_fkmigration.cpp:23: error: 'mxCOMPLEX' was not declared in this scope
it_mex_fkmigration.cpp:23: error: 'mxCreateDoubleMatrix' was not declared in this scope
it_mex_fkmigration.cpp:26: error: 'cvec2mxArray' was not declared in this scope
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell `mex` where the It++ library is located. Use the `-I` option to specify include paths; and `-L` option to specify library search paths.

```
mex it_mex_fkmigration.cpp -litpp -Ipath/to/it++/library -Lpath/to/libitpp
```

I've had trouble in the past with the `-L` option and had to work around it by specifying the entire path to the library using the `-l` option.

```
mex it_mex_fkmigration.cpp -lpath/to/libitpp/libitpp.a -Ipath/to/it++/library
```

Other options that can be passed to `mex` are listed in the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html) (under the *Mex script switches* section).

Also, the errors about `mxArray`, `mexErrMsgTxt` etc. indicate you haven't included `mex.h` in `it_mex_fkmigration.cpp`

Comment: Thank you! But, when I include the path to where my itpp/itmex.h file, which for me is /usr/local/include/itpp, I still get the no file found error.


>> mex it_mex_fkmigration.cpp -litpp -I/usr/local/include/itpp -L/usr/local/lib
it_mex_fkmigration.cpp:1:24: error: itpp/itmex.h: No such file or directory

    mex: compile of ' "it_mex_fkmigration.cpp"' failed.

Comment: @CarnezDavis If you have `#include "itpp/itmex.h"` and the file path is `/usr/local/include/itpp/itmex.h` the `-I` directive needs to be `-I/usr/local/include`